# Accept std::function with arbitrary inputs as input w/o Templates

Tags: c++11, math, input, lambda, std-function

For Learning Purposes:

I am creating a small numerical methods library and I am trying to implement the gradient currently I have done 2D gradient and 3D gradient . But I want to generalize this to higher dimensions.

Currently I have :

```
matrix<double> analysis::gradient_2D(std::function<double(double, double)> fn, double x, double y)
{
    matrix<double> R(2, 1);

    std::function<double(double)> fnX = [fn, y](double xVar){ return fn(xVar, y); };
    std::function<double(double)> fnY = [fn, x](double yVar){ return fn(x, yVar); };

    R(1, 1) = differentiateBest(fnX, x);
    R(1, 2) = differentiateBest(fnY, y);

    return R;
}

matrix<double> analysis::gradient_3D(std::function<double(double, double, double)> fn, double x, double y, double z)
{
    matrix<double> R(3, 1);

    std::function<double(double)> fnX = [fn, y, z](double xVar){ return fn(xVar, y,z); };
    std::function<double(double)> fnY = [fn, x, z](double yVar){ return fn(x ,yVar, z); };
    std::function<double(double)> fnZ = [fn, x, y](double zVar){ return fn(x, y, zVar); };

    R(1, 1) = differentiateBest(fnX, x);
    R(1, 2) = differentiateBest(fnY, y);
    R(1, 3) = differentiateBest(fnZ, z);

    return R;
}

// Where 

double analysis::differentiateBest(std::function<double(double)> fn, double x)
{
    return derivative_1_Richardson_6O(fn,  x);
}
// For brevity , derivative_1_Richardson_6O also has the same input as differentiateBest
```

I know it is verbose , but I like it

Question 
What I would like to do is to create a

```
// What do I do at the ...  ? 
matrix<double> analysis::gradient_ND(std::function<double(...)> fn, matrix<double>)
```

So that I can pass a std::function with arbitrary input say N and I will pass 
a vector which has N values.

How will I go about doing this ? If the answer is too long , links will be appreciated too .
Thank you.

PS: I saw a method using Templates , but if I use templates in the implementation , the I will have to change the .cpp file to something else right ? I would like to avoid. If using templates is the only way , then I will have to compromise. Thanks.

Comment: No, templates have nothing to do with the names of the files containing your translation units. True, the templates will probably be quite complicated, and you should organize the code somewhat, using header files; but this has nothing to do with templates per se, but with code complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct array_view {
  T* b = nullptr; T* e = nullptr;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }

  size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  T& front()const{return *begin(); }
  T& back()const{return *std::prev(end()); }

  T& operator[](size_t i)const{return begin()[i]; }

  array_view( T* s, T* f ):b(s),e(f) {};
  array_view() = default;

  array_view( T* s, size_t l ):array_view(s, s+l) {}

  using non_const_T = std::remove_const_t<T>;
  array_view( std::initializer_list<non_const_T> il ):
    array_view(il.begin(), il.end()) {}
  template<size_t N>
  array_view( T(&arr)[N] ):array_view(arr, N){}
  template<size_t N>
  array_view( std::array<T,N>&arr ):array_view(arr.data(), N){}
  template<size_t N>
  array_view( std::array<non_const_T,N> const&arr ):
    array_view(arr.data(), N){}
  template<class A>
  array_view( std::vector<T,A>& v):
    array_view(v.data(), v.size()){}
  template<class A>
  array_view( std::vector<non_const_T,A> const& v):
    array_view(v.data(), v.size()){}
};
```

an `array_view` is a non-owning view into a contiguous array of `T`.  It has converting constructors from a myriad of contiguous containers (if `matrix` is contiguous, a converter to `array_view` should be written).

Then:

```
matrix<double> analysis::gradient_ND(std::function<double(array_view<const double>)>, array_view<const double> pt)
```

is reasonable.

Using `array_view` causes no problem with `.h` and `.cpp` code splitting.  The only templates involved are either fixed (the `array_view` itself), or are resolved when constructing the `array_view`.

```
matrix<double> R(pt.size(), 1);

auto make_tmp = [pt]{
  std::vector<double> tmp;
  tmp.reserve(pt.size());
  for (double x:pt)
    tmp.push_back(x);
  return tmp;
};

std::vector<std::function<double(double)>> partials;
partials.reserve(pt.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < pt.size(); ++i) {
  partials.push_back(
    [&,i](double x){ auto tmp=make_tmp(); tmp[i]=x; return fn(tmp); };
  );
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < pt.size(); ++i) {
  R(1, i) = differentiateBest(partials[i], pt[i]);
}

return R;
```

note that creating array of `partials` is not actually needed.  You could just directly `differentiateBest`.

There is an inefficiency where `partials` reallocate each call.  If you are ok with making reentrancy not work (which will often be ok), creating a `tmp` and capturing it by-value, and modifying and restoring it after each call to `fn`, would boost performance.

```
  [&,i,tmp=make_tmp()](double x){ std::swap(tmp[i],x); double r=fn(tmp); std::swap(tmp[i],x); return r; };
```

is C++14 version.  C++11 version would create a `tmp` variable and capture it by-value.

Comment: Understand this will take me some time :) . Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.

Comment: @nnr the above array view probably contains typos: I have posted debugged versions elsewhere on SO.  Search `site:stackoverflow,com yakk array_view` if you need help fixing it.  Basically if you want to take any number of parameters, take a range of iterators: the above just abstracts it for any contiguous range.

Comment: I will come back if I have more questions. Thank you for the answer.